# how much cache size available in android?

Tags: android, caching

We have made a streaming player for android. now we want to store song data in the cash. How big the cache available for android app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maximum cache size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832462/maximum-cache-size)

Answer (score 0):

the documentation for getCacheDir() says

> You should not rely on the system
>   deleting these files for you; you
>   should always have a reasonable
>   maximum, such as 1 MB, for the amount
>   of space you consume with cache files,
>   and prune those files when exceeding
>   that space.

However if you use getExternalCacheDir(), you can use as much storage as it is available on the sd-card

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()

Comment: cache memory is depend upon device configuration u can not say 1 mb for the amount space.

Comment: I quoted the android API, and they don't say 1mb is max, they just recommend it