# Maximum cache size

Tags: android

I am planning to save an opened file to the android cache. But before I start I want to know the maximum size of the cache file, and how can I manage the cache size according to device?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29) says that:

> These files will be ones that get deleted first when the device runs
>   **low on storage**. There is no guarantee when these files will be
>   deleted.

and there is also a suggestion:

> Note: you should not rely on the system deleting these files for you;
>   you should always have a reasonable maximum, such as 1 MB, for the
>   amount of space you consume with cache files, and prune those files
>   when exceeding that space.

So, as I understand, cache can be as big as free memory on storage.

Comment: NO, cachce is very small in size...Read http://www.blaze.io/mobile/understanding-mobile-cache-sizes/

Comment: @AbhishekB Read with understanging, please. Below is the same answer. This article is about browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you understand it a bit:

http://www.guypo.com/understanding-mobile-cache-sizes/

Comment: Isn't it about browser's cache only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119405/android-how-to-increase-heap-size-at-runtime